# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays with Async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

*.html*

```
 <ion-select-option value="t.result[i].id" *ngFor="let t of (issueTypes$ | async); let i = index ">
            {{t.result[i].name}}
 </ion-select-option>
```

*.ts*

```
this.issueTypes$ = this.maintenanceService.get();
```

postman:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "KT5c6wdb8ecd94e",
            "name": "Need Batteries"
        },
        {
            "id": "RT5c6aa12600134",
            "name": "A/C Not working"
        }
    ]
}
```

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.
>       at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck
>   (common.js:3161)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22004)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23265)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23227)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23861)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23821)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MaintenancePage.html:19)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23813)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23209)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23450)

Can you tell me the issue here?

Comment: You probably meant `result` on the returned type: `let t of (issueTypes$ | async)?.result; let i = index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your json model from postman you should iterate over the `result` property which is the array in the returned model.

```
*ngFor="let t of (issueTypes$ | async)?.result; let i = index"
```

Then inside the containing html can access `t` directly which contains the object from the array. The index variable `i` is also no longer necessary.

```
{{t.name}}
```

Comment: Wow... really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to iterate over the result object.  You need to go a level deeper. So change your code to below:

```
<ion-select-option value="t.id" *ngFor="let t of (issueTypes$ | async)?.result; let i = index ">
            {{t.name}}
 </ion-select-option>
```

Comment: As `issueTypes$` is the observable/promise that resolves the `.result` should be called on it after it resolves. `(issueTypes$ | async)?.result`

Comment: Good point.  Honestly I wouldn't go about making ajax calls this way, but I'll update my answer.